# function file_exists does not work

Tags: php

In my webroot, i have a file called **exists.php** in which is this code to check if a file exists:

```
$filename = 'http://www.domain.nl/contact.php';
if (file_exists($filename))
    {
        echo "Document ".$filename." found...<br><br><br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Document ".$filename." not found...<br><br><br>";
    };
```

The file **contact.php** DOES exist but when calling exists.php he echoes: Document not found
When changing code to this:

```
$filename = 'contact.php';
if (file_exists($filename))
    {
        echo "Document ".$filename." found...<br><br><br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Document ".$filename." not found...<br><br><br>";
    };
```

Then it echoes: Document found.

Why does this not work with an absolute path?

Comment: Read the manual http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: A possible solution is do a http request (maybe using curl) and check if http status code is != 404 ...

Comment: no cross-domain files must be there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file_exists()` only works on stream wrappers that support the stat function.

These include:

- file://
- ftp://
- php://memory
- php://temp
- phar://
- ssh2.sftp
- rar://

http:// is not supported

Comment: You forgot `ftp://` (since PHP 5.0).

Comment: actually php://temp and php://memory don't work.  Not that they can't be stated, but the way their abstractions work there is nothing to stat unless the file handle is around.  So while file functions that need 'stat' that take in file handles will work. The ones that take paths like file_exists will not.